# powershell foreach returns multiplied values

Tags: powershell

I am trying to exclude a list of database names got from a csv file in a foreach loop. Instead of excluding me the names of dbs powershell multiplies me the number of entries:

PS:

```
$b1 = Import-CSV -Path C:\tst.csv
foreach ($ServerName in $Servers){
Foreach($Database in $SQLServer.Databases)
{


foreach($a in $b1){
  $server = $a.Name
  $db = $a.SQL
 
  if ($ServerName.Name -ne $server -and $Database.Name -ne $db){
    $Database.Name  
  }
}
}
}
```

CSV List:

```
Name,SQL 
server1,db1
server1,db2
server2,db1
```

output:

```
db0
db0
db0
db1
db1
db2
db2
etc
```

Servers:
s1
s2
s3

Can anyone give an advise on this?

Thank you!

Comment: `$Database` is probably a variable you had defined before testing this code, in the current code, it's not defined anywhere

Comment: $Database represents the variable that returns all the databases from the sql instance: Foreach($Database in $SQLServer.Databases){}

Comment: That's not what your code in question is reflecting. Make sure to update the code as you currently have it

Comment: done, updated code

Comment: Are you sure your code looks correct? You are importing a CSV (the same CSV) over and over per iteration of `$SQLServer.Databases`

Comment: it is outside the foreach loop, pasted wrong above

Comment: where is `$ServerName` coming from?

Comment: $ServerName holds the name of the sql servers, which in the foreach loop it is checked to be seen if it is equal or not with the one from the csv file

Comment: ...but, it's not declared anywhere in your above code. Is it separate from this?

Comment: updated code with $ServerName

Comment: Your code is still incomplete as you have variables which are not defined in the code you pasted. You need to paste a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

This condition in your inner loop:

```
$ServerName.Name -ne $server -and $Database.Name -ne $db
```

Is doing a *line-by-line* comparison which is likely to be `$true` more than once, we don't have enough information on this, but your issue is likely to be solved if you use [containment operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#containment-operators) for this (you can use `-notin` or `-notcontains`, it's up to you). As aside, your second inner loop is iterating over `$SQLServer` which is also not defined and unclear what it is.

```
$csv = Import-CSV -Path C:\tst.csv
foreach($ServerName in $Servers) {
    foreach($Database in $SQLServer.Databases) {
        if($ServerName.Name -notin $csv.Name -and $Database.Name -notin $csv.SQL) {
            $Database.Name
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the results in an array and call it with unique paramter

to creat the array

```
$array = @()
```

in the loop add this

```
$array +=   $Database.Name
```

then after loop

```
$array | select -Unique
```